# Displaying List does not display on WPF form

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to display a form with a dynamic list but the windows does not display anything. My class is as under

```
class ManagementFunctionModel
{
    #region members
    int _RangeLeft;
    int _RangeTop;
    int _RangeRight;
    int _RangeBottom;
    #endregion

    #region properties
    public int RangeLeft
    {
        get { return _RangeLeft; }
        set { _RangeLeft = value; }
    }

public int RangeTop
{
    get { return _RangeTop; }
    set { _RangeTop = value; }
}

public int RangeRight
{
    get { return _RangeRight; }
    set { _RangeRight = value; }
}

public int RangeBottom
{
    get { return _RangeBottom; }
    set { _RangeBottom = value; }
}

#endregion
```

}

The window class is as below

```
public partial class TestWindow : Window
{

    ObservableCollection<ManagementFunctionModel> mMngModelList = new   ObservableCollection<ManagementFunctionModel>();


    public TestWindow()
    {
        mMngModelList.Add(new ManagementFunctionModel() { RangeLeft = 4 });

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

The xaml is as under

```
<Window x:Class="Rules_Editor.TestWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Rules_Editor"        


    Title="ManagementFunctions" Height="342" Width="545">

<Grid Height="234" Width="461">
    <ListView x:Name="lstNames" ItemsSource="{Binding ManagementFunctionModel}" Margin="32,56,182,43" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView x:Name="grdNames">
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RangeLeft}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>    

</Window>
```

Please help me to find why I don't see anything on the GUI form? I expect to see one number 4 which I added in the constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, you should first change your POCO to have automatic properties. If you are going to have dynamic data within the POCO (properties change during run-time) you will then need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but for now, this will work:

```
public class ManagementFunctionModel
{
    public int RangeLeft { get; set;}
    public int RangeTop { get; set;}
    public int RangeRight { get; set;}
    public int RangeBottom { get; set;}
}
```

Next, in your code behind, you want to add the `DataContext`, as well as the the list you will be bound to. Since you are going to bind, the list needs to be a property.

```
public partial class TestWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<ManagementFunctionModel> MyList { get; private set; }

    public TestWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MyList = new ObservableCollection<ManagementFunctionModel>();
        MyList.Add(new ManagementFunctionModel() { RangeLeft = 4 });

        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

Lastly, you need to update your binding syntax in your XAML to use the new list property.

```
<Grid Height="234" Width="461">
    <ListView x:Name="lstNames" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" Margin="32,56,182,43" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView x:Name="grdNames">
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RangeLeft}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This won't work if you set the property value after the binding without implementing INotifyPropertyChanged. You'd need to set the property value before InitializeComponent

Comment: Yeah, I guess I am used to always having a base class w/ NotifyChanged implemented and not actually binding to properties within the code-behind.

Comment: As I understood, I need not implement NotifyChange if I am using ObservableCollection? The above exapmple does not work for me.

Comment: The example should work if you assign MyList to the new collection before calling InitializeComponent

Comment: Sorry about the lack of formatting, I'm on my phone (otherwise I'd have written an answer myself)

Comment: Also, ObservableCollection implements change notification for the *items in the list*, but not for the property that returns the list object itself

Comment: The declaration of MyList does not work. The error is 
Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Rules_Editor.ManagementFunctionModel>' is less accessible than property 'Rules_Editor.TestWindow.MyList'

Comment: Make your POCO class public

Comment: ManagementFunctionModel needs to be public. Make sure the code is the same as above

Answer (score 1):

First you should look into using auto properties and change your class like this :

```
class ManagementFunctionModel
{
    public int RangeLeft { get; set; }
    public int RangeTop { get; set; }
    public int RangeRight { get; set; }
    public int RangeBottom { get; set; }
}
```

About the issue where your data is not accessible it's because of the datacontext not being set in the window. In the constructor you can assign the data context to the window class like this :

```
public ObservableCollection<ManagementFunctionModel> mMngModelList{ get; private set; }

public TestWindow()
{
    mMngModelList = new ObservableCollection<ManagementFunctionModel>();
    mMngModelList.Add(new ManagementFunctionModel() { RangeLeft = 4 });

    InitializeComponent();

    this.DataContext = this;
}
```

Update:
the binding you currently have as :

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ManagementFunctionModel}"
```

should become

```
ItemsSource="{Binding mMngModelList}"
```

Make sure you make mMngModelList public

Comment: I'd add that the binding in `ListView.ItemSource` is wrong... it's binding to the class name `ManagementFunctionModel`, and not to a property on the `DataContext` (which is not even shown on his code)

Comment: @Franck I have made the changes you suggested but still does not work.

Comment: @Jcl what should be the binding in ListView.Itemsource?

Comment: If you are following this answer and setting the datacontext to the window, the window should have a property that returns your `ObservableCollection`, and you should bind to the name of that property

Comment: About the edit, correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think you can bind to a *field*, it needs to be a *property*,  isn't it?

Comment: As long as the variable is public you can bind it. The advantage of property is the get/set is "notifyPropertyChanged" ready which is what you want most of the time. `ObservableCollection` already implement everything needed for property changed event as loong as it's public so the view can see it

Comment: @Jcl Yes it needs to be a property.

Comment: @Franck the docs say binding uses reflection to look for properties if there's no dependency property registered by that nane. Admittedly, I've never tried it, but it should not work

Comment: @Jcl you are right my mistake for that part. I confused it's with Datacontext that do NOT need a property but only an object. But on the other hand property is not the only thing that works i have this binding that currently works in my software `<GridViewColumn Width="120" Header="Motor HP" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=[6]}" />`. You can also bind to iterator which is not a property.

Comment: AFAIK, an object's default indexer is always a property in c#. I don't think you can implement an indexer using a field.

Comment: @Jcl I always thought they were different. I checked on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) and it say `indexers resemble properties except that their accessors take parameters.`. I see by that they are not property but they do look like so. Probably depend how you read it.

Comment: @Franck as far as reflection goes, they act like properties in all respects (to differentiate, you query for PropertyInfo's index parameters)